# Trying to increase my game speed on score increments of 500, but I have too many if statements.

Tags: java

In my code, everytime the variable score is 500 more than first, the variable speed needs to increment. So, when score is 500: `speed++`. When score is 1000: `speed++` again, and so on.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Enemy {
    static int x = -100;
    static int y = -100;
    Player player;
    private int enemy_xspeed = 0;
    private int enemy_yspeed = 0;
    private int speed = 0;

    public Enemy(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void update(){
        if(Player.getX() < x){
            enemy_xspeed = -2 - speed;
        }
        if(Player.getX() > x){
            enemy_xspeed = 2 + speed;
        }
        if(Player.getY() > y){
            enemy_yspeed = 2 + speed;
        }
        if(Player.getY() < y){
            enemy_yspeed = -2 - speed;
        }   

        x += enemy_xspeed;
        y += enemy_yspeed;
    }

    public void scoreMethod(){
        //THIS BLOCK OF CODE BELOW TAKES TOO MANY LINES I NEED THIS HERE WRITTEN IN NOT MANY LINES
        if(GameClass.score == 500){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 1000){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 1500){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 2000){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 2500){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 3000){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 3500){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 4000){
            speed ++;
        }
        if(GameClass.score == 4500){
            speed ++;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need the `%` modulo operator.. `if(GameClass.score % 500 == 0){ speed++ }` If your score does not decrease as Trobbins noted below.

Comment: @Sid only if OP can confirm for us the score may never decrease.

Comment: Don't put your question as a comment in your code, it's not very obvious to people reading this question.

Comment: @Sid what do I have to do with %, than?

Comment: Maybe a switch tatement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer relies on the assumption your game score only ever increases.

```
public void scoreMethod(){       
    if(GameClass.score % 500 == 0){
        speed++;
    }
}
```

What this does is check to see if the game score can by divided by 500 without any remainders (just like your if statements).

---

However, if your game score may decrease, the above solution could negatively affect your game design:

> Score 480,
>   Score 490,
>   Score 500, speed increase (to level 2)
>   Score 480,
>   Score 490,
>   Score 500, another speed increase (Though now we're on level 3, when we should be level 2 again)

In that case, consider the following code which keeps track of when the speed was last increased, preventing the above repetition:

```
int lastSpeedIncrease = -1;  //class or 'global' variable
//initialize to -1 and not 0

public void scoreMethod(){               
    if(GameClass.score > lastSpeedIncrease){
        if(GameClass.score % 500 == 0){
            speed++;
            lastSpeedIncrease = GameClass.score;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this saved me a lot a unnecessary code :)